# Python logging - FileHandler path based on logger name?

Tags: python, logging

Is it possible to configure handler using a logger name?

I have a special log folder. Every user has its own log which they can download.

I call this log:

```
getLogger('engine.user.<current_user.pk>')
```

But I don't know how to set different file paths for different users so every user has it's own log file `/media/logs/<user.pk>.log`

The only way I know is to dynamically add handler when I use the logger but I would like to do that in the logging config if possible.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'user': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/media/logs/<user.pk>.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
        'engine.user': {
            'handlers': [],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'engine.user.*': {
            'handlers': ['user'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Is it possible?